# Aerospike spring data @Bin annotation missing in 2.0.1.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-data, aerospike

I am using `spring-data-aerospike` maven release `1.0.2.RELEASE` to store record having following schema:

```
Column1 : name=hash; type=Integer; constraints=primary key
Column2 : name=products; type=List;
```

As Column2 is a bin of type List, I am using `@Bin` annotation.

I tried switching over to `spring-data-aerospike 2.0.1.RELEASE` it shows compilation error `@Bin` annotation is absent . What do I use then instead of `@Bin`?

I could not find any release notes document for `spring-data-aerospike`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using standard spring-data annotation for document fields `@org.springframework.data.aerospike.mapping.Field`.